# Need help to identify the lines in Text using Python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

Text i had to Identify

```
^Form 26AS^

File Creation Date^Permanent Account Number (PAN)^Current Status of PAN^Financial Year^Assessment Year^Name of Assessee^Address Line 1^Address Line 2^Address Line 3^Address Line 4^Address Line 5^Statecode^Pin Code
26-07-2021^DDT6666LL^ACTIVE^2018-2019^2019-2020^    IT PRIVATE LIMITED^8-3-318/11/4B^RAKESH NAGAR^HHDHDDYGUDA^^^ANDHRA PRADESH^578563

^PART A - Details of Tax Deducted at Source^
Sr. No.^Name of Deductor^TAN of Deductor^^^^^Total Amount Paid / Credited(Rs.)^Total Tax Deducted(Rs.)^Total TDS Deposited(Rs.)
1^SOFTWARE TECHNOLOGIES PRIVATE LIMITED^BBBG74CGGG^^^^888610.00^12661.00^12361.00^
^Sr. No.^Section^Transaction Date^Status of Booking^Date of Booking^Remarks^Amount Paid / Credited(Rs.)^Tax Deducted(Rs.)^TDS Deposited(Rs.)
^1^164J^08-May-2018^F^15-Aug-2018^-^123610.00^12361.00^12361.00^

2^LIMITED^NNDD55569E^^^^^4143400.00^453300.00^413000.00^
^Sr. No.^Section^Transaction Date^Status of Booking^Date of Booking^Remarks^Amount Paid / Credited(Rs.)^Tax Deducted(Rs.)^TDS Deposited(Rs.)
^1^164J^31-Mar-2019^F^20-May-2019^-^4130000.00^413000.00^413000.00^

3^LIMITED^KKSFR324B^^^^^3443000.00^345300.00^95000.00^
^Sr. No.^Section^Transaction Date^Status of Booking^Date of Booking^Remarks^Amount Paid / Credited(Rs.)^Tax Deducted(Rs.)^TDS Deposited(Rs.)
^1^164J^18-Sep-2018^F^06-Nov-2018^-^950000.00^95000.00^95000.00^
```

How i identified lines by iterating on them:

```
f = file.readlines()
    for lines in f:
        company_info = f[2].split("^")
        company_values = f[3].split("^")
        deductor_info = f[6].split("^")
        deductor1_values = f[7].split("^")
        transaction_info = f[8].split("^")
        transaction1_values = f[9].split("^")
        deductor2_values = f[11].split("^")
        transaction2_values = f[13].split("^")
        deductor3_values = f[15].split("^")
        transaction3_values = f[17].split("^")
```

To identify these lines to perform actions/conditions I used to identify lines manually by considering line numbers but this way is not perfect because if I have to perform same actions up on another file these line numbers should not be the same for another similar file.
But how can i identify lines perfectly?
Please help by iterating on the lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the values are all separated by `^`, you can use `pandas`, particularly [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), to read them into a dataframe.

The metadata can be loaded as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df_meta = pd.read_csv('filename.txt', sep='^', skiprows=2, nrows=1)
```

Output `df_meta`:

|  | File Creation Date | Permanent Account Number (PAN) | Current Status of PAN | Financial Year | Assessment Year | Name of Assessee | Address Line 1 | Address Line 2 | Address Line 3 | Address Line 4 | Address Line 5 | Statecode | Pin Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 26-07-2021 | AATCS0112R | ACTIVE | 2018-2019 | 2019-2020 | IT PRIVATE LIMITED | 8-3-318/11/4B | JAYAPRAKESH NAGAR | YELLAREDDYGUDA | nan | nan | ANDHRA PRADESH | 500073 |

The rest of the file needs some tweaking as the table rows are split and are on every other line in the file:

```
from io import StringIO

with open('test.txt', 'r') as text:
  lines = [i.replace('\n', '') for i in text.readlines()[6:] if not i == '\n'] #create a list of lines, remove the top part and empty lines
  lines[0] = lines[0] + lines[2] #create header row
  lines = [i for i in lines if i!=lines[2]] # remove all headers in the rest of the list
  lines = [lines[0]] + [i[:-1]+j[:-1] for i,j in zip(lines[1:][::2], lines[1:][1::2])] #join every other line
  lines = '\n'.join(lines) #turn the list back into a string

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(lines), sep='^') #load the string with StringIO
```

Output:

|  | Sr. No. | Name of Deductor | TAN of Deductor | Unnamed: 3 | Unnamed: 4 | Unnamed: 5 | Unnamed: 6 | Total Amount Paid / Credited(Rs.) | Total Tax Deducted(Rs.) | Total TDS Deposited(Rs.) | Sr. No..1 | Section | Transaction Date | Status of Booking | Date of Booking | Remarks | Amount Paid / Credited(Rs.) | Tax Deducted(Rs.) | TDS Deposited(Rs.) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | SOFTWARE TECHNOLOGIES PRIVATE LIMITED | HYDG02074C | nan | nan | nan | nan | 123610 | 12361 | 12361 | 1 | 194J | 08-May-2018 | F | 15-Aug-2018 | - | 123610 | 12361 | 12361 |
| 1 | 2 | LIMITED | MUMM15369E | nan | nan | nan | nan | 4.13e+06 | 413000 | 413000 | 1 | 194J | 31-Mar-2019 | F | 20-May-2019 | - | 4.13e+06 | 413000 | 413000 |
| 2 | 3 | LIMITED | VPNA02864B | nan | nan | nan | nan | 950000 | 95000 | 95000 | 1 | 194J | 18-Sep-2018 | F | 06-Nov-2018 | - | 950000 | 95000 | 95000 |

You can export the dataframes to [csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) files or other output formats like [dictionaries](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html), See `panda's` [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/index.html).

**UPDATE for your full data**

The code below is adapted to work with the full data files. The main difference is that it processes each part seperately and collects everything in a dictionary:

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

dfs = {}

with open('filename.txt', 'r') as text:
  text = text.read() #read file
  parts = ['^PART' + i for i in text.split('^PART') if not 'No Transactions Present' in i][1:] #only keep parts with transactions

  for part in parts:
      lines = [i for i in part.split('\n') if i.strip()] #create a list of lines, remove empty lines
      name = lines[0][1:].split(' -')[0] #get part name from first line
      lines = lines[1:] #slice list to drop the first - header - line

      header = ''.join([line for line in lines if 'Sr. No.' in line][:2]) #create header row by merging split headers
      lines = [i for i in lines if not 'Sr. No.' in i] # remove all headers in the list
      split_points = [i for i, e in enumerate(lines) if e[0].isdigit()] + [len(lines)] #find the indexes of where the different parts start by checking which lines start with an integer
      parts = [lines[split_points[n]:split_points[n+1]] for n, ind in enumerate(split_points[:-1])] #create a list of lists of parts

      if len(parts[0]) > 1:
        parts = [header] + [i[0] + l[:-1] if len(i)>1 else i[0] for i in parts for l in i[1:]] #merge lines and add header row
        flat_text = '\n'.join(parts) # flatten list to string
        dfs[name] = pd.read_csv(StringIO(flat_text), sep='^') #assign pandas dataframe to dictionary
      else:
        flat_text = '\n'.join([header] + [item for sublist in parts for item in sublist])
        dfs[name] = pd.read_csv(StringIO(flat_text), sep='^')
```

The dictionary `dfs` contains dataframes of all parts that contain data. `dfs.keys()` will show you the keys. You can then get a dataframe from the dictionary by key, eg `dfs['PART A']` to process them further or store them (eg `dfs['PART A'].to_csv('filename.csv')`.

Comment: bro your answer gives the perfect pattern in which I need a file, but there are more lines in my text file after the above mentioned lines, they spoiling the format answer how can I share you the total file, Please help once watching the total file.
Thank You @RJ Adriaansen

Comment: You can share the file with [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) for example. I'll look into it later today.

Comment: I think that the problem is that you didn't specify what exactly you would like to extract and what the desired output would look like. You can add that to the question and request reopening the question. It will also work favorably if you show your (failed) attempt to solve it yourself. In any case I updated the answer with regards to your full file. Take a look, I hope it's educative.

Comment: Bro thank you so much, i am a fresher joined as intern software engineer and I got this task to be done, you literally helped me a lot in this. i was struggling from last 3 days but I am not even to move ahead. you saved me a lot. Thank You so much. @RJ Adriaansen

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are iterating through all lines by using:

```
for lines in f:
```

And inside the loop you are getting 10 lines manually. It's not what you want to do.

For the answer: You Are not sure if the information you are looking for is in the same line for all files. So you should find another way to find the line that hast that information.

For example to find `company_info`, you can look if a line contains a certain value that is unique to it.

Let's say the text `Permanent Account Number` appears only in `company_info`. So:

```
for line in f:
    if "Permanent Account Number" in line:
        company_info = line.split("^")
```

For other lines you can find some unique texts too.